# How to deal with time out exception for wait.until

Tags: python, selenium, wait

Get time out exception when wati.until excute. I've no idea why about it, since the img element is not shown to user when refresh web page.

```
wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//img[@src='//www.ibm.com/i/c.gif']")))


raise TimeoutException(message)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: ''
```

**Here's my code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver    
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait # available since 2.4.0
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC # available since 2.26.0
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui

driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www-01.ibm.com/products/hardware/configurator/americas/bhui/launchNI.wss') 
driver.find_element_by_id("modelnumber").send_keys("7383AC1") 
driver.find_element_by_name("submit").click() 
element1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[contains(text(),'SLES for SAP Apps 8 Skt Virt Unlimited Subs Only 5Yr (5731SLX)')]")
id=element1.get_attribute('for')
driver.find_element_by_id(id).click()

#updated with wait until
wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//img[@src='//www.ibm.com/i/c.gif']")))
```

Comment: Checking this XPath `//img[@src='//www.ibm.com/i/c.gif']` against that  page, results in exactly 205 images. Even the first one is visible, it has a height of 1 and is explicitly set to `display:block` in the CSS styles. So what exactly are you expecting to not be there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved my problem, by modifing codes like below:

```
driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www-01.ibm.com/products/hardware/configurator/americas/bhui/launchNI.wss') 
driver.find_element_by_id("modelnumber").send_keys("7383AC1") 
driver.find_element_by_name("submit").click() 
element1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[contains(text(),'SLES for SAP Apps 8 Skt Virt Unlimited Subs Only 5Yr (5731SLX)')]")
id=element1.get_attribute('for')
driver.find_element_by_id(id).click()
print driver.title

wait=ui.WebDriverWait(driver,300)
image1=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[@src='//www.ibm.com/i/c.gif']")
print image1.get_attribute('class')
div1=driver.find_element_by_id("genMask_c")
wati.until(EC.staleness_of(driver.find_element_by_id("genMask_c")), 'visible')
driver.find_element_by_id("continueTop").click()
print driver.title
```

Comment: I am doing something like `wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, i)))` but I am still getting timeoutexception while if I remove this, for one instance, click works.